# What authentication information in Windows access tokens?

Tags: windows

> What authentication information in Windows access tokens?

I'm particular interested in, whether the token stores the user's credentials (username/password) or Kerberos tickets?

How can I inspect this?

Comment: Some of this information may be stored, except not in the token but in the LSA session instead.

Comment: So, credentials are never stored in the access token? How is the access token linked to LSASS.exe (LSA)?

Answer (score 1):

The token does not store the user's credentials.
These credentials are used to construct the token, but are not included in it.

By default, Windows credentials are validated against the Security Accounts Manager (SAM) database on the local computer, or against Active Directory on a domain-joined computer, through the Winlogon service.

See the Microsoft article
[Access Tokens](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/access-tokens)
to see a list of the details included in a token.

See the Microsoft article
[Credentials Processes in Windows Authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/credentials-processes-in-windows-authentication)
for a description of the processes that construct the token.

See the Microsoft article
[How Access Tokens Work](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/cc783557%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
to see a detailed description of the items making up the token.
I include here the graphical display of the token from the article:

[image]

This subject is vast, and while Microsoft does a credible job of describing it,
not everything is documented.

Answer (score 0):

For a view of the more important contents of an access token, use the Process Explorer tool from the SysInternals tools. Run it as admin. Double-click on a process - or right-click on it - and pick the "Security" tab of the resulting dialog. That's the access token, though the window doesn't say so anywhere.

Grab the SysInternals tools from Microsoft [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/).

Comment: Thank you. But this displays the processes' access token, and not the access token of the user?

Comment: @user111854 Where did you find that users even have 'access tokens' on Windows?

Comment: @grawity - don't they? If you look at the illustration in the other answer, the access token is associated to a user.

Comment: @user111854: Yes, but it is associated in the opposite way than you think. The token is owned by a process, and only describes the privileges that the token-holding process has (user SID, group SIDs, LSA session ID, etc.). It is not user-wide, instead it's inherited from one process to another (like environment variables), and different processes belonging to the same user can have different tokens.

Comment: @user111854  No, they don't. The "user" is not an object that can have an access token. Each process does. Threads can have them too. Read the Security chapter of _Windows Internals_.